Why does MonoDevelop have a MSB3276 warning?
I have a .NET WinForms project, and am porting it to Linux. The target framework of this project is .NET Framework 4. This project builds well in Visual Studio Express 2012 (specifically, "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop", which is shown in its about dialog) on Windows. It also builds, and seems to work well, in MonoDevelop (specifically, version "7.8.4 (build 2)", which is shown in its about dialog) on Linux. But, when building in MonoDevelop on Linux, MonoDevelop has a MSB3276 warning, saying "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly", while Visual Studio Express 2012 on Windows does not have this warning. So, why is there this difference? Is anything wrong or problematic? Can I fix this warning?

You should move away from Mono, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-end-of-mono/ and choose another UI framework https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea
